# How can i change timezone in neo4j?

Tags: time, neo4j, timezone

I want to change default timezone from UTC to another timezone. How it will be possible? I tried 
RETURN apoc.date.format(timestamp(),'ms', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH/mm/ss')
but it returns utc time on localhost.

Answer (score -2):

Example answer:

```
RETURN apoc.date.format(timestamp(),'ms', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss',"Europe/Paris")
```

Method from the source:

```
public String format(final 
                     @Name("time") Long time
                    ,@Name(value = "unit", defaultValue = "ms") String unit
                    ,@Name(value = "format",defaultValue = DEFAULT_FORMAT) String format
                    ,@Name(value = "timezone",defaultValue = "") String timezone) 
    {
        return time == null ? null : parse(unit(unit).toMillis(time), format, timezone);
    }
```

The `timezone` parameter is further passed to Java `TimeZone` class constructor. 
From [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)) as to what it should contain -

> the ID for a TimeZone, either an abbreviation such as "PST", a full
>   name such as "America/Los_Angeles", or a custom ID such as "GMT-8:00".
>   Note that the support of abbreviations is for JDK 1.1.x compatibility
>   only and full names should be used.

The source code of this project - 
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.3/src/main/java/apoc/date/Date.java

For more info, have a look at this article about dates in APOC
http://xclave.azurewebsites.net/2018/02/28/better-know-apoc-apoc-3-date-parse-format/

Comment: Can you go into a little bit more detail as to what information is at the links? Link-only answers suffer from link-rot; a quick summary of what is there would make this answer much higher quality.